# Add external link to an <a> element inside a Click Event Listener Div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onclicklistener

I'm having trouble adding a link to a button inside a card. the card is wrapped in a div element which when clicked automatically expands and closes.

Is there anyway to remove this functionality just when clicking on the details button? So it acts as a normal link?

Here is the code:
https://codepen.io/candroo/pen/wKEwRL

Card HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card__image-holder">
    <img
      class="card__image"
      src="https://source.unsplash.com/300x225/?wave"
      alt="wave"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="card-title">
    <a href="#" class="toggle-info btn">
      <span class="left"></span>
      <span class="right"></span>
    </a>
    <h2>
      Card title
      <small>Image from unsplash.com</small>
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card-flap flap1">
    <div class="card-description">
      This grid is an attempt to make something nice that works on touch
      devices. Ignoring hover states when they're not available etc.
    </div>
    <div class="card-flap flap2">
      <div class="card-actions">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var zindex = 10;

  $("div.card").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var isShowing = false;

    if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
      isShowing = true;
    }

    if ($("div.cards").hasClass("showing")) {
      // a card is already in view
      $("div.card.show").removeClass("show");

      if (isShowing) {
        // this card was showing - reset the grid
        $("div.cards").removeClass("showing");
      } else {
        // this card isn't showing - get in with it
        $(this).css({ zIndex: zindex }).addClass("show");
      }

      zindex++;
    } else {
      // no cards in view
      $("div.cards").addClass("showing");
      $(this).css({ zIndex: zindex }).addClass("show");

      zindex++;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `target` of the `event` and see if it is an `<a>` using [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

Something like:

```
$("div.card").click(function (e) {

    // only run when not an `<a>`
    if(!$(e.target).is('a')){
       e.preventDefault();
       //the rest of your code 
       ....
    }
});
```

Comment: did you get it to work inside codepen? it doesn't seem to respond when i added you suggestion

Comment: Did you just wrap what you already have with the `if()` in my answer?

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for the quick response. At some point in the future i will definitely sit down and take some time to learn JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Jquery but with javascript you can do this inside your code:

```
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  links.forEach(link => link.addEventListener('click', (e)=>e.stopPropagation()))
```